# Parse JSON style text with filehelpers

Tags: c#, parsing, filehelpers

So in a CSV file we have this `"foo='foo value';bar='bar value';"` as one column value

I have done some research and figure worst case I can simply enclose that value with { "..." } and replace ';' with ',' and '=' with ':' then just use a JSON parse but i am new to file helpers so i figure there could easily be a way to accomplish this with that lib no extra work. I have been searching around but likely not asking `google` the right question.

that said i am posting the question.

worst case i am going to build out a custom parser and do the above.

hope this question is clear, if not please ask and i will edit best i can to clarify.

Comment: I understand the question, and off the top of my head I can't think of a way to use file helpers with key/value pairs. Personally, I would likely do the string replace and read it in as natural JSON, or, replace `;` with `"\n"` and read it in as an ini file (fewer string replacements).

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, maybe you could provide an example of the INI method you are proposing?

Comment: Posting a custom method that should handle all the grunt work for you. (I haven't tested the code, so it may be prone to some typo's, but it should work for the string you supplied)

Comment: @KraangPrime, the end goal is to get a strong type result so i may go the json parse route i posted. i did give you a +1 as that is a viable solution. if you want to edit to a strong type return of Foo i will mark as answer

Comment: I agree, for strong type, the solution below doesn't qualify.  You could hybrid with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3188462/3504007)  to build a strong type wrapper for the dictionary result.   Or you could convert to JSON, and use DataContracts.  Lots of ways to work this problem :)

Comment: @KraangPrime, I agree there are plenty ways. think i will go the JSON route and return the object i am looking for. thank you for taking the time and your answer is a good one. hope you get many an up vote friend. will post my solution once its written

Comment: For your pleasure (if like me, you like to work minimal), I wrote this little class to handle converting `json` [from web url/api, or string] to strongly typed classes (predefined `DataContract`'s)  [JSON to DataContract](http://pastebin.com/9HZ72HNu)

Answer (score 1):

This method should handle reading in the values from the format you supplied and return a `Dictionary` containing all the values in keyPairs.

```
public Dictionary GetData(string data) {
    Dictionary<string, string> dictRet = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    strKeyPairs = data.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (string strKeyPair in strKeyPairs) {
        strKeyValuePair = strKeyPair.Split(new[] { "=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (strKeyValuePair.Length > 0) {
            if (strKeyValuePair.Length == 2) {
                dictRet[strKeyValuePair[0]] = strKeyValuePair[1];
            } else {
                dictRet[strKeyValuePair[0]] = string.Empty;
            }
        }

    }

    return dictRet;
}
```